# Is there a word for the floating speed of an object?

Tags: single-word-requests

I realize that it is easy to find data regarding the amount of water that moves through a river at a given point but I was interested in finding out the likely rate at which an object would float at said point and was having difficulty tuning my search for information about that concept. Is there a word out there that encapsulates that idea?

Comment: Wouldn't any object freely "floating" move at the same rate as the water carrying it? Certainly not faster, and slower would require a weird geometry or entail ultimately sinking.

Comment: @Dan Bron that does indeed make sense. I was mostly getting hung up on the fact that the rate of river flow was volumetric whereas I was hoping to get a rate that was linear.

Comment: Surely you have something like liters/meters/second (or gallons/feet/second), no? Then the surface of the water (and anything freely floating on it) would be moving at a simple meters/second.

Comment: @Dan Bron if all that I know is that a measurement was taken at a point on a river and it was determined that 1000 cubic meters of water was moving per second there, would that then mean that a boat floating at that point would be floating at 1000 meters per second? I think not. I must be misunderstanding you.

Comment: Ah, no, you're right, I had a thinko.  You'd have to know the geometry of the river: in particular, its surface area. (Also you'd have to ignore or fuzz facts like local eddies, that water at the banks has greater drag, all that stuff.) Maybe you can google "surface speeds"?

Comment: All you need to do is take 2-3 semesters of "fluid dynamics" in mechanical engineering school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not be diverted by incomplete notions about fluid physics that are appearing in some responses. One term I suggest to you is "surface drift". This is a term widely understood by those who study the movement of things that float on the sea, rivers and lakes and that move with the water, or are driven through the water by wind. If you want only one word, use "drift".

Answer (score 1):

Would movement upon the water in a linear motion not be referred to as "drifting" at "x" knots?  With "x" being a numeric value?

Comment: Yes, it is as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

The speed at which something floats is the same as the speed of the river. This is called **[river] velocity**.

http://www.geography-site.co.uk/pages/skills/fieldwork/fluvial/vel.html

Answer (score -1):

You might look to the word **viscosity** as a starting point.

> a quantity expressing the magnitude of internal friction, as measured by the force per unit area resisting a flow in which parallel layers unit distance apart have unit speed relative to one another.

Comment: Viscosity is irrelevant to the question.  Viscosity accounts for the resistance of a fluid to motion and has very to do with the drift of an object with a current.

Comment: To add to my comment above. Viscosity is irrelevant to the  question as asked. Viscosity accounts for the resistance of a fluid to motion and has only secondary effect on the drift of an object with a current. As a glance at any dictionary will reveal, it is not a suitable word to describe the motion of anything at all.

Answer (score -1):

You may also search for **Hydrodynamics**

> a branch of physics that deals with the motion of fluids and the
>   forces acting on solid bodies immersed in fluids and in motion
>   relative to them

Comment: I think this answer is a little closer to the concept I am searching for than viscosity but both answers are helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You might spend a year studying hydrodynamics but still not know  the answer your simple question.

Comment: @Anton very well. Let's go with drift then

Comment: Thanks. I can assure you that you are on safe ground (so to say!) with that word.